# How to extract trace data from Jaeger

Tags: python, kubernetes, trace, jaeger

I am trying to learn kubernetes recently. I have already deployed jaeger (all-in-one) by istio on kubernetes, and everying works well. Although I can see the trace information on the jaeger UI, I don't know how to extract these trace data by python. I want to use these data to do root causes location of microservices.
I think there must be some API to access these data dicectly by python but I don't find it. or can I access the cassandra using python to get these data?.
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? How did you deployed Jaeger, any tutorial/guide? What is your environment, local, cloud, are you using minikube, kubeadm, kind? Could you share your config, your steps to replicate? Did you get any error? What did you try and what was result?

Comment: you are in a completely wrong direction. I explained the dynamics here, if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66565177/how-to-investigate-latency-spikes-in-openshift/66566445#66566445

Comment: @suren, thank you for your reminding. It's very useful. But I just need to get the trace data instead of knowing how to trace a service. Maybe I described my question in a wrong way. I have already changed my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I had got into a completely wrong direction. I thought that I have to access the backend storage to get the trace data, which actually make the problem much more complex. I got the answer from github discussion and here is the address https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/discussions/2876#discussioncomment-477176